# commitOffsets method of ConsumerConnector class hangs in an infinite loop?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer which has following skeleton:

```
         private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String connStr)
          {  
             Properties externalConsumerProperties = ConsumerProperties.getConsumerProperties();

             Properties internalConsumerProperties = new Properties();

             // Properties below must not be changeable externally
             internalConsumerProperties.put("zookeeper.connect", connStr);
             internalConsumerProperties.put("group.id", "sm-publisher");
             internalConsumerProperties.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
             internalConsumerProperties.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
             internalConsumerProperties.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
             internalConsumerProperties.put("consumer.timeout.ms", "15000");
             internalConsumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");

             Properties props = new Properties();

             if(externalConsumerProperties != null)
             {  
                props.putAll(externalConsumerProperties);
             }

             props.putAll(internalConsumerProperties);

             return new ConsumerConfig(props);
          }

    main()
   {
        ConsumerConnector connector = null;  
        connector=kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig(connectionString));
        kafkaStream = createStream(connector);
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = kafkaStream.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            //process message 
            // ...............
            connector.commitOffsets();
        }
   }
```

This consumer works pretty good in normal scenario. But after fetching a message and before committing the offset if connection to the zookeeper server breaks down, and consumer tries to commit the offset then it stuck in an infinite loop. Is there any way to make it come out of that??